# IndexOutofBoundsException: I cant solve it

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Im trying to do a basic java task, there are ships and i have to give the coordinates of them using an import file in which there are characters representing the movements of the ships. (N = +1 to North, S= +1 to South, E= +1 to East, W= +1 to West)

I want to count the coordinates in a two dimensional Array, in which the first column represent the Vertical, the second column represents the Horizontal directions.

Get the following problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at robotok.main(robotok.java:36)
```

I marked line 36 in the source code.

```
ArrayList<String> control = new ArrayList<String>();
int coords[][] = new int[control.size()][2]; // index = robot sorszáma / [] Hosszúság / [] Szélesség

try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(robotok);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        control.add(line);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
}

for (int i = 0;i<control.size();i++) {
    char[] directions = control.get(i).toCharArray();

    for (int j =0;j<directions.length;j++) {
        if (directions[j] == 'N') {
            coords[i][0] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'S'){
            coords[i][0] ++;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'W'){
            coords[i][1] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'E'){
            coords[i][1] ++;                     /////THIS IS 36///// 
        }
    }
}

for (int i =0;i<coords.length;i++) {
     System.out.print("The "+i+". ship's coords: "+coords[i][0]+" ; "+coords[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Please use Ctrl + Shift + F while in Eclipse or Ctrl + Alt + L while in Intellij IDEA before you post a code on SO.

Comment: Just take a piece of paper and apply the steps of your algorithm on it until you see the problem. Either that or learn how to use a debugger, but the former is a more useful learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
ArrayList<String> control = new ArrayList<String>();
int coords[][] = new int[control.size()][2]; // index = robot sorszáma / [] Hosszúság / [] Szélesség

try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(robotok);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        control.add(line);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
}

for (int i = 0;i<control.size();i++) {
    char[] directions = control.get(i).toCharArray();

    for (int j =0;j<directions.length;j++) {
        if (directions[j] == 'N') {
            coords[i][0] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'S'){
            coords[i][0] ++;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'W'){
            coords[i][1] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'E'){
            coords[i][1] ++;                     /////THIS IS 36///// 
        }
    }
}

for (int i =0;i<coords.length;i++) {
     System.out.print("The "+i+". ship's coords: "+coords[i][0]+" ; "+coords[i][1]);
}
```

use

```
ArrayList<String> control = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(robotok);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        control.add(line);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
}

int coords[][] = new int[control.size()][2]; // index = robot sorszáma / [] Hosszúság / [] Szélesség

for (int i = 0;i<control.size();i++) {
    char[] directions = control.get(i).toCharArray();

    for (int j =0;j<directions.length;j++) {
        if (directions[j] == 'N') {
            coords[i][0] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'S'){
            coords[i][0] ++;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'W'){
            coords[i][1] --;
        }else if (directions[j] == 'E'){
            coords[i][1] ++;                     /////THIS IS 36///// 
        }
    }
}

for (int i =0;i<coords.length;i++) {
     System.out.print("The "+i+". ship's coords: "+coords[i][0]+" ; "+coords[i][1]);
}
```

The problem was that you intended to initialize `coords` based on `control`, which has a size of 0 before you add the elements. Later on, after the elements are added, `control` becomes larger and you try to reference `coords`' element at certain indexes above its size. Hence the exception.

Answer (score 5):

You create the `coords` array before you have added the elements to `control`, while it is still size 0. You need delay creating it until the list has reached its final size.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the control ArrayList its initial length is 0 and does not insert any element in it before accessing its length 
Due to which the Array length of the coords is also zero and you are trying to access the array beyond its length 
so, it is advised to insert the value to control before assigning the value to the lenght